# How can I access untranslated field values in a translated view row?

Tags: views, 8, tokens

If you add the title field to a view you can use the token `title__raw` as a pattern. I just created a custom field for use in view named dossier_status and I need to create something a like `dossier_status__raw` token. The reason is that the status can be translated to different languages but I need the status always in english to use it as a css class. How can I accomplish this?

[image]

For the moment I have another field named `dossier_status_machine_name` (with the status always in english) But I think that this is not the best approach.

Comment: Sounds like Views raw values don't get translated?

Comment: @NoSssweat really I don't know if the raw value is translated, I need some value that will remain exactly in all the site languages.

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer, you access raw values with the property name, which is in most field types `__value`. But raw doesn't mean untranslated. So the real question is: How can I access untranslated field values in a translated view row. In php you can get the untranslated entity with `getUntranslated()`. This should also work in twig. But is there a solution in UI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems not to be possible to access untranslated field values in a rewrite token pattern for text fields. You can get the untranslated value from the field in a template by using the row entity and getting the untranslated entity `{{ row._entity.getuntranslated().field_dossier_status.value|clean_class }}`, but using templates in Views I would avoid if possible. So this may be a better approach:

**Static**

Supposed that there is a limited number of CSS classes, in most cases CSS is static, use a field `field_dossier_status` of the type *list (text)* with a allowed values list:

```
dossier-status-class-1| Dossier Status Class 1
dossier-status-class-2| Dossier Status Class 2
...
```

You can translate the second part of the allowed values in *Translate content fields*.

Now if you access the raw value from this list field in a Views token pattern `__value` you get the untranslated first part

```
<div class="{{ field_dossier_status__value }}">
```

and this result:

```
<div class="dossier-status-class-1">
```

**Dynamic**

If the CSS is dynamic you can use a dynamic method for the allowed values, see [Dynamic Default and Allowed Values for List Fields in Drupal 8](https://chromatichq.com/blog/dynamic-default-and-allowed-values-list-fields-drupal-8), which btw. gave me the initial idea for this answer to the question you asked some days ago. You could even parse the dynamic CSS for the classes it provides and fill them in the allowed values list.

Answer (score 1):

Lets pretend your status is `open` and `closed`

Give this a try (untested) in rewrite results of your dossier status field.

```
{% if field_dossier_status == 'open'|t %}

<div class="dossier-open">{{ field_dossier_status }}</div>

{% elseif field_dossier_status == 'closed'|t %}

<div class="dossier-closed">{{ field_dossier_status }}</div>

{% endif %}
```

If it does not work, then try with a views fields template file, **views-view-fields--[view-name].html.twig**

```
{% if fields.field_dossier_status.content|striptags == 'open'|t %}

<div class="dossier-open">{{ fields.field_dossier_status.content }}</div>

{% elseif fields.field_dossier_status.content|striptags == 'closed'|t %}

<div class="dossier-closed">{{ fields.field_dossier_status.content }}</div>

{% endif %}
```

Hopefully one of these will work.

Comment: Fixed error in my code.

Comment: thanks, your answer works, I will wait a few days for accept the answer to see if other users comes with other answers ;-)